# Can/should we edit "did you google it?" out of answers?

Tags: discussion, unfriendly-or-unkind

Today I faced a programming problem. So I googled it. As always, Stack Overflow is the #1 hit. The top answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/343643/963076), which is helpful and not wrong, comes with some unnecessary snark:

> Google would help you if you used the right terms to search "get fractional and whole part out from double java"

An astute observer, Chris, comments:

> Actually this page is the first hit on a google search for "get fractional and whole part out from double java" =)

And highlights why *"did you google it?"* is distracting and lowers the quality of the answer. Yes I googled it. That's what led me here.

In the answerer's defense, his post was from 2008. Things were certainly different in 2008. Back then we were all used to forums where you could/should chide people for their lack of resourcefulness and time-wasting inquiries. But now that it's almost 2020, and Stack Overflow is *the* de facto source of answers such as this, this kind of admonishing people to "go be more resourceful and stop wasting my time" is counterproductive.

My question: may we / should we edit these out of answers?

Comment: Frankly, I'm not sure why this meta question is even necessary. Does the text add anything material to the answer? No? Edit it out. Same as rants about "M$FT" or "tanks in advance" or anything else.

Comment: @HereticMonkey nor I.  My reaction was of course not, followed by being surprised the obviously unacceptable text hadn't been removed by anyone who looked at this before me.

Comment: Edit out the snark... but i don't think suggesting different terms to use in your research moving forward is a bad thing. After all, if you've asked a question, you've clearly used the wrong search terms.

Comment: Editing out search terms seem like a bad idea... I.e. @DanNeely edit to original question removes useful information instead of editing out text that some may consider slightly offensive.

Comment: Side note: since people like comments on votes... I voted on the post strictly based on "useful and clear" and not weather I agree or disagree with the suggestion...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I upvoted your comment so I could add this comment on my vote on your comment on your vote.

Comment: After the comments and answers, I did a double-take and realized: perhaps the "snark" was just his way of helping the OP clarify terms. I can relate: I've struggled writing a good google query. Sometimes asking a SO question helps me zero in on the right terms to use (better yet, it's flagged as a duplicate question and I'm directed to the right question).

Comment: @ryvantage now that you mention it, if you look at the initial revision of the question, they did use different terms when they asked it. It definitely made that part of the answer sound more snarky when someone edited the question to use almost the same phrasing.

Comment: That is not snarky, it is a simple statement of helpful fact.

Comment: After @DanNeely edited the answer, now Chris' comment seems odd. Should the comment be deleted too?

Answer (score 15):

It depends on whether it actually contains any useful information.

If all that's said is some form of "you should've googled this" then it's useless noise, regardless of whether it's nice or not. Whether or not someone should've been able to find their answer with a google search is opinion-based, and people will be able to form their own opinions about how much effort the asker put into researching their question without the answer containing an opinion about that. It also makes you wonder *why* that person bothered answering it if they thought it was so trivial that they needed to criticize someone for asking it.

On the other hand, if someone gives some specific search terms that could be used to find more information about the problem, that can actually be useful, and editing it out will damage the answer. Maybe the person would've had more luck with their googling if they just knew the word for the thing.

Granted, that's a bit hard to believe when googling the exact question title instantly gets you to the answer, but again, if you really think it's that stupid of a question, then why are you answering it?

---

After looking at the specific question you asked about again, I noticed that the original question was

> How do I get Mantissa and Exponent from double in jsp/java?

So at the time it was written, I think the part of the answer suggesting better search terms definitely seems more helpful than snarky. After the question was edited to use the same terms suggested in the answer, I think it was good to remove that part of the answer, because it was really no longer useful, and unfortunately easy to misconstrue as condescending without the original context.

In my opinion that would have ideally happened at the same time the question was edited.

Comment: Good find. The general question still remains but this specific example was not good

Answer (score 8):

Seems like a good suggestion to me.

Since the original purpose of Stack Overflow is a database for questions and answers - the question-answer pair should be posted here, even if it is present on some other site that could be found via "google".

So, as far as I see it, the fact that the questioner could have found the answer to his question via a search engine does not disqualify it from being posted on Stack Overflow. And answers containing "did you google it" from high-reputation users might mislead newcomers into thinking otherwise.

Comment: No. Stack Overflow isn't a replacement for official documentation. If the answer would be trivially found in Google, users can confront the asker why the solutions didn't work and demand from OP to show it research work.

Comment: @Braiam How do you "show" that you've googled? Even if you did, perhaps you just didn't enter the right terms, or your Google is biased towards other results than my Google. I'd *assume* anyone tries a Google search first before asking, you'd be insane not to. The fact that they ended up asking means they didn't find anything. Even if they simply didn't enter the "right" terms, that alone qualifies the question to be on SO, because more people will enter the "wrong" terms in the future and then probably find the SO post with the "wrong terms", but now pointing to the right answer.

Comment: @Braiam SO is a database of answers to technical questions about programming. It is not a help center nor a forum where you are expected to ask only if you didn't manage to find the answer. Case in point - on SO it is perfectly normal to post a question even if you already know the answer yourself. And then answer it yourself for the purpose of expanding the database. In my opinion same logic applies to answers found on third-party sites via search engine. I never said it was a "replacement for documentation".

Comment: @deceze you show the results. What did you find, and how it doesn't help you. "I found nothing" is only valid when you are somehow search for furry with safe search on.

Comment: @KarolisKoncevičius You got backwards, on forums is the only place where the same questions get asked again and again, because useful information usually gets buried under irrelevant conversation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's a good idea.

We generally do this for questions too. Things like "thanks in advance," "help pls," etc. is generally accepted by the community as okay to edit out of questions. Thus, it is reasonable that this should apply to answers as well.

As a general rule, if it can be fixed, edit it out. If it can't, down-vote it and move on--unless it has very serious problems like spam, extremely rude or offensive, or is otherwise abusive to the site. In that case, raise the appropriate flag.